# Getting net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME while calling telephone number from HTML page in Android

Tags: android, html, error-handling, android-manifest

I am getting "net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME" while calling a telephone number option from an HTML page in Android. Do I need to add any permission(s) in the manifest to get this working? I haven't added anything in the manifest so far.  Here's the HTML Code:

`<a href="tel:+1800229933">Call us free!</a>`

Comment: can you please post html code ?

Comment: <a href="tel:+1800229933">Call us free!</a>

Comment: try by removing '+' from your telephone number.

Comment: @Parvaz Bhaskar I tried it but it didnt work out.

Comment: @Karthik, your this problem is resolved or not?

Answer (score 38):

The following should work and not require any permissions in the manifest (basically override shouldOverrideUrlLoading and handle links separately from tel, mailto, etc.):

```
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);

    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if( url.startsWith("http:") || url.startsWith("https:") ) {
                return false;
            }

            // Otherwise allow the OS to handle things like tel, mailto, etc.
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity( intent );
            return true;
        }
    });
    mWebView.loadUrl(url);
```

Also, note that in the above snippet I am enabling JavaScript, which you will also most likely want, but if for some reason you don't, just remove those 2 lines.

Comment: Works like a charm for me. Someone select it as best answer

Comment: How can I donate?

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue occurring with `mailto:` and `tel:` links inside an iframe (in Chrome, not a webview). Clicking the links would show the grey "page not found" page and inspecting the page showed it had a ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME error.

Adding `target="_blank"`, as suggested by [this discussion of the issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=364522) fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Add the target attribute to the anchor tag: `<a href="mailto:my@email.com" target="_blank">link text</a>`

Comment: strAbout = strAbout + "<br /> Email: " + jsonObj.getString("email");        
strAbout = strAbout + "<br /> Phone Number: " + jsonObj.getString("contact_no");

I am loading this string on web view  after this 
  Spannable sp = new SpannableString(Html.fromHtml(strAbout));
  Linkify.addLinks(sp, Linkify.ALL);
  final String html = "<body>" + Html.toHtml(sp) + "</body>";
  webViewAbout.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  webViewAbout.loadData(html, "text/html", "utf-8");
I am not able to add **target="_blank"**

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

**main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**MyActivity.java**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.loadData("<a href=\"tel:+1800229933\">Call us free!</a>", "text/html", "utf-8");
    }

}
```

**Please add this permission in AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
```