# Facebook browser/webview, can't send sms: net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Tags: android, facebook, webview, sms

I need to send an SMS from a webpage advertised on Facebook, but there is a major issue: the protocol `sms:` doesn't work at all, giving the error `net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME`.

Is there a way to leave the app and open a link in the default browser, or another way to send the SMS (by opening the SMS outbox)?

Comment: please try solutions provided in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24697429/getting-neterr-unknown-url-scheme-while-calling-telephone-number-from-html-pag

Comment: Unfortunately adding target="_blank" doesn't work, and of course I cannot edit the Facebook app manifest