# Error scheme webview

Tags: android, webview

I have a problem with my "webview" application, both the links to emal and the telephone contact, once clicked on in the application gives me this error:

> net :: ERR_UNKNOW_URL_SCHEME

Do you know how I can solve?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41693263/android-webview-err-unknown-url-scheme

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting net::ERR\_UNKNOWN\_URL\_SCHEME while calling telephone number from HTML page in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24697429/getting-neterr-unknown-url-scheme-while-calling-telephone-number-from-html-pag)

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what happen to you without code that guess your mWebView.loadUrl is point.

your web String should looks like "https://www.google.com.tw/"

do not use "www.google.com"

hope it help.

following below:

```
mWebView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com.tw/")
```